# simple way to sort a list based on max value of a property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that I get from joining tables, this list has low range and high range values, goal is to select that row which has maximum LowRange value, in the example below,

I select rate 15.5 since it has the highest lowrange val

```
    Rate        LowRange    HighRange
    ---------------------------------------
    12.5        300000      0
    15.5        1500000     300001
    17.5        NULL        1500001
```

any ideas how i can achieve this using linq, c# would be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CuongLe has the simplest answer.

There is a nice extension to Linq (originally written by Jon Skeet as part of [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), or also [see here](http://nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable/)) called `MaxBy()` which would let you do this:

```
var max = list.MaxBy(item => item.LowRange);
```

This is a lot more efficient because it is only O(N), whereas `OrderByDecending()` is `O(N*Log(n))`

Comment: Thanks Matthew Watson and stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You can `OrderByDescending` on `LowRange` then get `First`

```
 list.OrderByDescending(x => x.LowRange).First();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply:) let me try